# Magento Indexer Bug in 1.9.4.0

Tags: indexer, magento-1.9.4.0

currently i have a bug(?) in Magento CE1.9.4.0 - where i just upgraded from 1.9.3.4.

My problem is that the indexer is not able to lock files.

I created a simple php file to reproduce the error:

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app('');

$indexProcess = Mage::getModel('index/process');
$indexProcess->setId('something');
$indexProcess->lockAndBlock();

if ($indexProcess->isLocked()) {
  var_dump('locked');
} else {
  var_dump('something went wrong');
}
```

The output is everytime: something went wrong

To verify that this is not a problem with the upgraded version i tried to run the same code on a freshly installed magento 1.9.4.0 -> same error, it even did not work out to move the code to a different server. Also i tried to run the Code in different Versions of PHP(5.6 & 7.2).

Did someone else had the same error and maybe a solution?

Ah and of course i checked the file permission in the var/locks path

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check php logs? Maybe some file rights issue. Also checkout Magento LTS where many bugs have been fixed and are being fixed.